# Do you lose reputation when a post is deleted?

Tags: support, reputation, deleted-questions

I'm just wondering if you lose reputation when a post that you contribute to is deleted.

Example: If you were to edit a question and that question gets deleted would you lose the 2 rep that you gained from the edit?

Answer (score 3):

**You lose reputation from upvotes.**

If you were the asker of the question, all reputation changes (both positive & negative) from the question disappear.

If you edited the question, those 2 points will not disappear; they reward you for contributing to the *site* (by cleaning up questions & answers), not for contributing to that specific question.